# Slidy jquery plugin not working in browser but will in DW

Tags: jquery

I'm a noob at this and I'm in the middle of building a portfolio site for myself.  I grabbed a jquery plugin for a slideshow type deal.  Now it works in DW, but when i throw it on my host ftp, and go to the site, the script doesnt seem to be loading.  heres the URL to the site i can add more deets if needed.
Thanks so much.

http://www.akashicsound.com

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the case but you are missing:

1. images/image-1.jpg
2. images/image-2.jpg

on your site are they those images thats in your slide? upload them in that case to your server.

Comment: Silly me it was a case sensitive error.  "image"  not "Image"   my gawd.  Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: still just saying 404 on those images, re-upload them on the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the images are missing. You should make sure that the image paths are set correctly.